# Function which verifies if a string is includes in an other one in Lisp

Tags: string, lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to write a function which verifies if a string is included in another one in Lisp but I cannot

For example :

```
(string-include 'abd 'abbbe) => nil

(string-include 'ghf 'dghfd) => ghf
```

Here is my function:

```
(defun string-include (string1 string2)
  (cond
    ((not string1) 0)
    ((not string2) 0)
    ((.... (string1) (string2)) (string1 (string-include string1 (cdr string2))))
    ((string-include  string1 (cdr string2)) ) )
```

Comment: You have your function returning the symbol whose name is included in the name of other, and nil otherwise.  What do you do in the case that the first symbol is nil.  E.g., If you do `(string-include 'nil 'vanilla)` you'll get `nil` back, but you can't tell whether it's because `nil` is in `vanilla` or because it isn't.

Answer (score 7):

### Return an index or the substring, not a symbol

In your question, you used this example:

> ```
> (string-include 'abd 'abbbe) => nil
> (string-include 'ghf 'dghfd) => ghf
> ```

Assuming that you're returning the *symbols* **nil** and **ghf**, you'll run into an ambiguity if you ever want to check whether a string contains the substring **NIL**.  E.g., with this approach, you'll have:

```
(string-include 'nil 'vanilla) => nil
```

Did that return **nil** because **"NIL"** is in **"VANILLA"**, because it isn't?  It's ambiguous and you can't tell.  Instead, you could return the actual string, since the *string* **"NIL"** is a true value.  Even better, if you return the *index* of the string, then you find out *where* in the other string the first string appears.  That's the way that the built in function **search** behaves, for instance.

### Directly, using SEARCH

You can implement this in terms of [**search**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_search.htm):

```
(defun substringp (needle haystack &key (test 'char=))
  "Returns the index of the first occurrence of the string designated
by NEEDLE within the string designated by HAYSTACK, or NIL if it does
not occur.  Characters within the string are compared by TEST, which
defaults to CHAR= (for case-sensitive comparison)."
  (search (string needle)
          (string haystack)
          :test test))
```

Note the use of the [**string**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_string.htm) function to convert from [*string designators*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_s.htm#string_designator) (characters, strings, and symbols) to the strings that they designate.  Remember that with the standard settings, the reader upcases the names of symbols, so the symbol **cat** designates the string **"CAT"**.  Finally, since this returns the result from **search**, it does double duty for you:  it returns the *index* of the first occurrence if there is an occurrence, and **nil** otherwise.  Remember that everything except **nil** is a *true* value (even 0), so you can use the result as a boolean or as an index (as long as you check that it's not **nil**).  Here are some examples:

```
CL-USER> (substringp "cat" "concatenate")
3

CL-USER> (substringp "dog" "concatenate")
NIL

;; Default upcasing of symbol names means that the 
;; result of 'cat is a symbol named "CAT", which is not 
;; in "concatenate". 
CL-USER> (substringp 'cat "concatenate")
NIL

;; You can test the characters with CHAR-EQUAL, which
;; is case insensitive, in which case "CAT" is in 
;; "concatenate".
CL-USER> (substringp 'cat "concatenate" :test 'char-equal)
3
```

### Using recursion

Your code, and the code that uselpa showed in another answer, are more recursive in nature.  That in and of itself is not a problem, but recursive string processing in Common Lisp is prone to a few pitfalls.  It's inefficient to make lots of new stings by using **subseq**, so lots of sequence functions in Common Lisp take **:start** and **:end** arguments, or in the case of functions that take two sequences, **:start1**, **:end1**, **:start2**, and **:end2** arguments.  By using these, you can recurse and change the *indices* into the strings, rather than creating entirely new strings. For instance, [**string=**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_stgeq_.htm) lets you compare two strings.

```
;; "toc" is in both "octocat" and "toccata"
CL-USER> (string= "octocat" "toccata" :start1 2 :end1 5 :end2 3)
T
```

Working with these kinds of functions requires a bit of care to make sure you don't provide any indices that are out of range, but it's not too bad, and you don't end up copying any strings.  Here's a version of **substringp** that accepts these start and end parameters, and uses a local recursive function to do the actual processing.

```
(defun substringp (string1 string2
                   &key
                     (start1 0) (end1 nil)
                     (start2 0) (end2 nil))
  "Returns the index of the first occurence of the substring of
STRING1 bounded by START1 and END1 within the substring of STRING2
bounded by START2 and END2, or NIL if the string does not appear.  The
index is a position within STRING2 as a whole."
  ;; First, compute the actual strings designated by STRING1 and
  ;; STRING2, and the values for END1 and END2, which default to the
  ;; length of the respective strings.  Also get the length of the
  ;; substring in STRING1 that we're looking for. This is done just
  ;; once.  The actual recursive portion is handled by the local
  ;; function %SUBSTRINGP.
  (let* ((string1 (string string1))
         (string2 (string string2))
         (end1 (or end1 (length string1)))
         (end2 (or end2 (length string2)))
         (len1 (- end1 start1)))
    (labels ((%substringp (start2 &aux (end2-curr (+ start2 len1)))
               (cond
                 ;; If end2-curr is past end2, then we're done, and
                 ;; the string was not found.
                 ((not (< end2-curr end2)) nil)
                 ;; Otherwise, check whether the substrings match.  If
                 ;; they do, return the current start2, which is the
                 ;; index of the substring within string2.
                 ((string= string1 string2
                           :start1 start1 :end1 end1
                           :start2 start2 :end2 end2-curr)
                  start2)
                 ;; If that doesn't match, then recurse, starting one
                 ;; character farther into string2.
                 (t (%substringp (1+ start2))))))
      (%substringp start2))))
```

Comment: So how can i write exactly my function ?

Comment: Why in your example (substringp "cat" "concatenate") returns 3 ?

Comment: @yoan15 as I explained in my answer, if the substring occurs in the string, then toy get the index back (which is always a true value). So 3 is the index of cat in concatenate, and it's true because cat is in concatenate.

Comment: @yoan15 it looks like your string-include function has almost the same signature as  my substringp; I'm not sure what other part you need.

Answer (score 4):

Judging by your code, what you are looking for is something like this:

```
(defun string-include (string1 string2)
  (cond
   ((zerop (length string1)) nil) ; string1 is empty (no need to test it every time)
   ((> (length string1) (length string2)) nil) ; string1 is longer than string2
   ((string= string1 (subseq string2 0 (length string1))) string1) ; string2 starts with string1
   (t (string-include string1 (subseq string2 1))))) ; otherwise shorten string2 by 1 and start over
```

This works but it is inefficient and not idiomatic Common Lisp. Just make sure that you actually pass strings and not symbols like in your example:

```
? (string-include "abd" "abbbe")
NIL
? (string-include "ghf" "dghfd")
"ghf"
```

Of course, [Joshua's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34620827/1193075) is the recommended solution.

**EDIT**

Added a version that works with both symbols and strings (but returns strings anyway). I took the opportunity to include one of Joshua's suggestions:

```
(defun string-include (string1 string2)
  (let* ((string1 (string string1)) (length1 (length string1)))
    (if (zerop length1)
        nil 
        (labels ((sub (s)
                   (cond
                    ((> length1 (length s)) nil)
                    ((string= string1 s :end2 (length string1)) string1)
                    (t (sub (subseq s 1))))))
          (sub (string string2))))))
```

Testing:

```
? (string-include "abd" "abbbe")
NIL
? (string-include "ghf" "dghfd")
"ghf"
? (string-include 'abd  'abbbe) 
NIL
? (string-include 'ghf  'dghfd) 
"GHF"
? (string-include "ghf" '|dghfd|) 
"ghf"
? (string-include '|ghf|  "dghfd") 
"ghf"
```

Comment: Thank you but for symbols it's not a problem. There is a command which transforms a symbol into a string.

Comment: So is this the kind of solution you're looking for?

Comment: Many string processing functions, including [**string=**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_stgeq_.htm), accept start1, start2, end1, and end2 keyword arguments precisely so that you don't have to make lots of copies with **subseq**. In this case, it'd be helpful to replace `(string= string1 (subseq string2 0 (length string1)))` with `(string= string1 string2 :end2 (length string1))`.  Adding these keyword arguments to **string-include** could help to avoid the **subseq** in the last case, too.

Comment: Also, isn't the first case backwards?  If string1 is the empty string, then it's a substring of every string.  E.g., `(string-include '|| 'foo)` should produce `||` not `nil`, right?  (Actually, this raises the issue, too, about words containing nil.  E.g., `(string-include 'nil 'foo) => nil` and `(string-include 'nil 'vanilla) => nil`.

Comment: @uselpa Just for fun, I added a recursive version to my answer that makes use of the start and end keyword arguments.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor all your remarks are correct of course but you should ask the OP. I do not endorse this solution per se, I just think that this is what the OP is looking for. To me this looks like a *Scheme* assignment that for some reason is done in Common Lisp. So I did it "the Scheme way", but it looks awkward in CL ;-)

Comment: @uselpa With your solution and with the function symbol-name which transforms a symbol into a string, how could I adapt it ?  For example (symbol-name 'efg) returns "efg". So to convert (string-include 'abd 'abbbe) into  (string-include "abd" "abbbe") in the function, how could I adapt it ?

Comment: You could write a second function which does the conversion and call the first function. Or you could define the above function as an internal function (using `labels`) and do the conversion before calling the inner function. What are your constraints? Does it have to be all in a single function?

Comment: @uselpa My constraint is that I would like to put it in a single function. How would you make it please ? I'm having difficulties

Comment: @uselpa Okay thank you but your first solution it's more understandable. Last question in the same way: How would you make a function which returns the character's adress in a string?                                                                                                   For example: (position "b" "abds") => #\b or (position 'y 'abcd) => nil      I should do that as the first solution ?

Comment: I suggest you open a new question for this. Please be precise what you mean by address, this is not clear in your example.

Comment: @uselpa By adress i mean character in fact for differentiating the symbol. I can't open a new question, I have to wait a few days :(

Comment: For example (code-char 65) => #\A so returns the character